# How to dispose a Flutter screen from iOS native code using channel method invocation?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm learning to integrate Flutter in native iOS apps.
So far I was able to navigate to Flutter screens from an iOS `View`, but I'm stuck dismissing the Flutter screen using the method described in using platform channels at https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=ios-channel-swift-tab.

That example is using a Flutter `app` which communicate with the underlying native platform so in `AppDelegate.swift` the `FlutterMethodChannel` and the `setMethodCallHandler` receive a method invocation and perform the desired native logic.

In the example at https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/project-setup and following at https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=entrypoint-library-swift-tab#dart-library Flutter is instead integrated as a `module`, so there is no `AppDelegate.swift` to handle the `FlutterMethodChannel` and method invocations as modules only use obj-c and create `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m`.

I dit try creating `AppDelegate.swift` manually but then on `import Flutter` fails with no such module error.

So I tried creating one for the native iOS app as I created a SwiftUI app to test the process and importing Flutter doesn't throw errors as Flutter is indeed an installed module, but then I get `Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: force unwrapped a nil value` exception when unwrapping `window?.rootViewController`.

My idea is to call `controller.dismiss(animated:true)`.

I'm going in circles as I'm a bit rusty in Swift, can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Many many thanks.

Flutter to Swift notification method:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Utilities {
  static void closeFlutterView() {
    // Platform channel to notify Swift
    const MethodChannel channel =
        MethodChannel('com.example/close_flutter_view');
    channel.invokeMethod('close');
  }
}
```

Flutter screen:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_module/utilities.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void screenAEntrypoint() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: ScreenA(),
  ));
}

// @pragma('vm:entry-point')
class ScreenA extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScreenA({super.key});

  @override
  State<ScreenA> createState() => _ScreenAState();
}

class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> {
  dynamic backButton = Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoIcons.back : Icons.arrow_back;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Screen A"),
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(backButton),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              Utilities.closeFlutterView();
            }),
      ),
      body: const Text("Screen A entry point"),
    );
  }
}
```

Swift main file:

```
import SwiftUI
import Flutter
import FlutterPluginRegistrant

// Create a Flutter Engine
class FlutterDependencies: ObservableObject {
    let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "my flutter engine");
    let flutterEngine2 = FlutterEngine(name: "my flutter engine 2");
  init(){
      flutterEngine.run(withEntrypoint: "screenAEntrypoint", libraryURI: "package:flutter_module/screen_a.dart");
      flutterEngine2.run(withEntrypoint: "screenBEntrypoint", libraryURI: "package:flutter_module/screen_b.dart");

      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine);
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine2);
  }
}

@main
struct flutter_integration_testApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var flutterDependencies = FlutterDependencies()
    
      var body: some Scene {
          WindowGroup {
              ContentView().environmentObject(flutterDependencies)
          }
      }
}
```

Swift main View:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Flutter


struct ContentView: View {
    // Flutter dependencies are passed in an EnvironmentObject.
    @EnvironmentObject var flutterDependencies: FlutterDependencies
    var body: some View {
      Text("iOS View")

      Button("Show Flutter!") {
        showFlutter()
      }
        Button("Show Flutter2!") {
          showFlutter2()
        }

    }

  func showFlutter() {
      // Get the RootViewController.
      guard
        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
          .first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive && $0 is UIWindowScene }) as? UIWindowScene,
        let window = windowScene.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow),
        let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
      else { return }

      // Create the FlutterViewController.
      let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(
        engine: flutterDependencies.flutterEngine,
        nibName: nil,
        bundle: nil)
      flutterViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
      flutterViewController.isViewOpaque = false

      rootViewController.present(flutterViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func showFlutter2() {
        // Get the RootViewController.
        guard
          let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive && $0 is UIWindowScene }) as? UIWindowScene,
          let window = windowScene.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow),
          let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
        else { return }

        // Create the FlutterViewController.
        let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(
          engine: flutterDependencies.flutterEngine2,
          nibName: nil,
          bundle: nil)
        flutterViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        flutterViewController.isViewOpaque = false
        rootViewController.present(flutterViewController, animated: true)
      }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Flutter

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("Your code here")
         
        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive && $0 is UIWindowScene }) as? UIWindowScene;
        let window = windowScene?.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow);

        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController;
                
        let flutterChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example/close_flutter_view",
                                                          binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
                
        flutterChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
                    
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            
            guard call.method == "close" else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                return
            }
            controller.dismiss(animated: true);
        })

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to it.
Apart from the `SystemNavigator.pop(animated: true);` called in Flutter screen, I wanted to try and use the invokeMethod to dismiss the view instead.
Now the approach I was trying in AppDelegate was correct but as I got hold of the root view controller in the `showFlutter()` method and presented the Flutter screen from it, then I tried setting  the MethodCallHandler there and respond to the `close` method.
Indeed it works as I was expected it to work from the AppDelegate.

```
func showFlutter() {
        // Get the RootViewController.
        guard
          let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive && $0 is UIWindowScene }) as? UIWindowScene,
          let window = windowScene.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow),
          let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
        else { return }
        let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(
            engine: flutterDependencies.flutterEngine,
            nibName: nil,
            bundle: nil)
        flutterViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        flutterViewController.isViewOpaque = false
        rootViewController.present(flutterViewController, animated: true)

        var methodChannel : FlutterMethodChannel?;
            methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example/close_flutter_view",
                                                 binaryMessenger: flutterDependencies.flutterEngine.binaryMessenger)
            methodChannel?.setMethodCallHandler({ //[weak self]
                (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
                    switch(call.method) {
                    case "close":
                        rootViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
                    default:
                        print("Unrecognized method name: \(call.method)")
                    }
            })
      }
```